# After restore SQL Database in Azure DTU stay in 100% full time

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, restore

A programmer unintentionally erased the production database.
We use the option of Azure 'Restore Deleted Database', and it worked.
But after restoring the database, is accusing DTU 100% all the time.
[image]

We stopped all sites and services that used the database of production, and after starting again, back to accuse DTU 100%.
Before normal was staying with some peaks up to 40%.

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please send the details of your DB name, server name and subscription id to shantanu dot kurhekar @ microsoft dot com

Update :

Worked offline with Jonathan to get this resolved.

When a database on Azure SQL DB service is restored, it is restored using the service tier that was applicable at the restore point with its default performance level. This could be different from the tier the database was at before restore.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/01/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/

Comment: Wish you guys made it clearer how long is left in restoring a database. When restoring a 'traditional database' from a backup file (not bacpac) it gives a percentage and then when it's completed you're done. With Azure I really have no clue where it is in the process, and also if increasing DTUs will linearly reduce the restoration time.